# Jquery Disable past days with checking of Another Date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have two textfields (datepicker) like below image.

[image]

When I select date from the **FROM** field a datepicker appers and selecting a date.

After that I want to disable the past dates of **FROM** Field in **TO** textfield.

My code is below :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var startcheck;
    $( "#datepick" ).datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) 
        {
            startcheck = $(this).val();

            $( "#datepickto" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',showOtherMonths: true,selectOtherMonths: true,minDate: "'"+startcheck+"'"});
        }
    });

    $( "#datepickto" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',showOtherMonths: true,selectOtherMonths: true,minDate: "'"+startcheck+"'"});

});
```

How can I solve this issue ?

Anybody Please help me !!!!!!!!!!!

@Barmar : please look your answer and what i asked.!!

Editted with answer

```
        function showRestricedDatePicker()
    {
        $("#datepick").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', 
            maxDate: new Date(), 
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            onClose: setRange 
        });

        $("#datepickto").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', 
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            beforeShow: setRange
        });
    }
    function setRange()
    {
        currentDate = new Date();
        var fromDate = $('#datepick').datepicker('getDate');
        if(fromDate != null && fromDate != '') {
            return { minDate: fromDate }        
        }
    }
```

html

```
 <td><input type="text" name="date" id="datepick" placeholder="From" autocomplete="off" onclick="showRestricedDatePicker()" ></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="dateto" id="datepickto" placeholder="To" autocomplete="off" onclick="showRestricedDatePicker()"></td>
```

Comment: @Barmar This is not answer for which he is looking for

Comment: you are absolutely right Sunil

Comment: OK, I've reopened, but what's the difference?

Comment: @barmar He is asking for set a range in open to Datepicker

Comment: @SunilPachlangia Where did he say that? He said that he just wants to set the minimum date on the `To` datepicker to the date in the `From` datepicker. That's exactly what the linked question shows how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call showRestricedDatePicker onclick of your from date picker input box

```
function showRestricedDatePicker()
{
    $("#fromDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', 
        maxDate: new Date(), 
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onClose: setRange 
    });

    $("#toDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', 
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        beforeShow: setRange
    });
}
function setRange()
{
    currentDate = new Date();
    var fromDate = $('#fromDate').datepicker('getDate');
    if(fromDate != null && fromDate != '') {
        return { minDate: fromDate }        
    }
}
```

Edit : 
Write this

```
<input type="text" id="fromDate" name="fromDate" autocomplete="off" readonly="readonly" onmouseover="showRestricedDatePicker()"  onclick="showRestricedDatePicker();" />

<input type="text" id="toDate" name="toDate" autocomplete="off" readonly="readonly" onmouseover="showRestricedDatePicker()"  onclick="showRestricedDatePicker()" />
```

And Remove this code

```
 $('#datepick').click(function()
        {
            showRestricedDatePicker();
        });
        $('#datepickto').click(function()
        {
            showRestricedDatePicker();
        });
```

Comment: hi Sunil, Answer is good and working fine. salso. please check my editted code.

Comment: the datepicker appears only after second click of the textfield    ?

Comment: Where did you write that function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74792/discussion-between-jishad-p-and-sunil-pachlangia).